# scala quasiquotes convert Tree to AppliedType

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-quasiquotes, scala-macro-paradise

I wan to infer an implicit value of an `AppliedType`, here's what I've done

```
val valueType = accessorTree.returnType
val encoderType = tq"DatumEncoder[$valueType]" // returns a Tree
val encoder = c.inferImplicitValue(encoderType) // require a Type
```

But the `tq` returns a `Tree`

> How Can I convert it to a **Type**

Comment: Did you try `encoderType.tpe`? There are many examples for example for structural types, existential types etc in http://den.sh/quasiquotes.html

Comment: Or you could: `import reflect.runtime.currentMirror
import tools.reflect.ToolBox
val toolbox = currentMirror.mkToolBox()` and then: `typecheckType(encoderType)`

Comment: @Jatin Can you make an answer. The link is pretty fine!!! I just need such things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [link](http://den.sh/quasiquotes.html) contains detailed response for `tq` types interpolator.

You could just do: `encoderType.tpe`

Or you could:

```
import reflect.runtime.currentMirror 
import tools.reflect.ToolBox 
val toolbox = currentMirror.mkToolBox()

def typecheckType(tree: Tree): Type = toolbox.typecheck(tree, toolbox.TYPEmode).tpe
typecheckType(encoderType)
```

Comment: Sorry `encoderType.tpe` returns `null` because it is not typechecked yet.